# Running bash command on server

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to run the bash command pdfcrack in Python on a remote server. This is my code:

```
bashCommand = "pdfcrack -f pdf123.pdf > myoutput.txt"
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

I, however, get the following error message:

```
Non-option argument myoutput2.txt
Error: file > not found
```

Can anybody see my mistake?

Comment: It looks like pdfcrack thinks that `>` is also a filename. Try writing to a file with python using the stdout

Answer (score 1):

`>` is interpreted by shell, but not valid otherwise.

So, that would work (don't split, use as-is):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, shell=True)
```

(and `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` isn't useful since all output is redirected to the output file)

But it could be better with native python for redirection to output file and passing arguments as list (handles quote protection if needed)

```
with open("myoutput.txt","w") as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(["pdfcrack","-f","pdf123.pdf"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    f.write(process.read())
    process.wait()
```

Comment: You don't want to mix `shell=True` with a list argument.

Comment: oh, right, changing that. I wouldn't do like that anyway, second solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `Popen` is a list containing the command name and its arguments. `>` is not an argument to the command, though; it is shell syntax. You *could* simply pass the entire line to `Popen` and instruct it to use the shell to execute it:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, shell=True)
```

(Note that since you are redirecting the output of the command to a file, though, there is no reason to set its standard output to a pipe, because there will be nothing to read.)

A better solution, though, is to let Python handle the redirection.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['pdfcrack', '-f', 'pdf123.pdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
with open('myoutput.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for line in process.stdout:
        fh.write(line)
        # Do whatever else you want with line
```

---

Also, don't use `str.split` as a replacement for the shell's word splitting. A valid command line like `pdfcrack -f "foo bar.pdf"` would be split into the incorrect list `['pdfcrack', '-f', '"foo', 'bar.pdf"']`, rather than the correct list `['pdfcrack', '-f', 'foo bar.pdf']`.

Comment: you could use `shlex.split()` if the command line comes exclusively as a string. Quotes are then taken into account. but yeah argument list is better.

Comment: The first sentence of the documentation makes me run away from that module: "The shlex class makes it easy to write lexical analyzers for simple syntaxes *resembling that* of the Unix shell." Besides, I've never seen the need to encode your argument list into a string only to break it back into a list.

Comment: that could be handy when reading from a configuration file or when creating your own shell for instance. Probably not here.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is `>` in command.

It doesn't treat this as redirection to file because normally bash does it and now you run it without using bash.

Try with `shell=True` if you whan to use bash. And then you don't have to split command into list.

```
subprocess.Popen("pdfcrack -f pdf123.pdf > myoutput.txt", shell=True)
```